# How to navigate from one view to another view like iphone inside tab bar - Android apps

Tags: android, tabs

I'm new with android development. Can someone help how to navigate from one view to another view inside tab bar like iPhone for Android apps?

Thank you.

Comment: Please do some R&D before posting Question.

Comment: @Smith please let him do some R&D or atlist let him show that what he has done so far then Give your Code.

Comment: Hi Smith, I have do the research. But I can not get how to navigate from one view into another inside tab bar view. I have build the tab bar. The problem is the first view link to the 2nd view at the same tab. When I intent to the second view, the tab view is not show.

Comment: you mean you are trying to call another activity from tab?

Answer (score 1):

**check viewswitcher in android**- 
basic premise is you put the  tag around 2 different layouts in your xml file, and then declare a variable in your main activity, a ViewSwitcher.  Then, to switch  between views, just call switcher.showNext() and switcher.showPrevious().

**Example:-**

```
private ViewSwitcher switcher;
private static final int REFRESH_SCREEN = 1;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

switcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.profileSwitcher);
startScan();
}
      ... Finish the rest of your program
```

And this is how you will switch between the views

```
switcher.showNext();  // Switches to the next view
switcher.showPrevious();  // Switches to the previous view
```

your xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewSwitcher xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/profileSwitcher"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
<TextView
    android:text="Loading…"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressbar"
    android:gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
<TextView
    android:text="Finished!"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

</ViewSwitcher>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Frame Layout in your XML file for that purpose. It can be implemented as:

```
android:id="@+id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<FrameLayout 
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

   <AnalogClock
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="A Semi-random Button"             

         />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/tab2"
    android:text="@string/goToClock"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"


    />

</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, I have build tab view. But inside tab view, I have a button and intent to another view. But When I intent to it, the whole tab view is not show. Can you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to use TabView, i have given one sample here:

```
public class Welcome extends TabActivity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
       // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    intent = new Intent(Welcome.this, Select.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Show All").setIndicator("Show All",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.showall)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent(Welcome.this, Insert.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Insert").setIndicator("Insert",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.insertrelative)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    intent = new Intent(Welcome.this, Shownetwork.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Show Network").setIndicator("Show Network",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.showrelativeinfo)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);



 // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent(Welcome.this, Addnetwork.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Add Network").setIndicator("Add Network",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.addrelativeinfo)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

And this is Welcome.xml

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout  android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" android:background="@drawable/images"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Create a tab activity that handles all the child tabs, create an activity for each tab. and pass the intent to that activity in the main tab we have created before. you can also assign a icon image and the name to that tabs.*

```
public class TabActivity extends android.app.TabActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab
```

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, StockList.class);

```
    spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("stocks")
            .setIndicator("Stocks",
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.stocklist_tab))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AddStock.class);
    spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("Add stock")
            .setIndicator("Add Stock",
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.stockchange_tab))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```